# How to convert html into data image uri

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, data-uri

Well my question seems weird but here what i want to achieve . Similar to the below link 
http://www.wovenlabelsuk.com/craft-hobby-labels/wl-02.html

I want a text to embed with image and i get data image url back using ajax. I know how to create data image uri but not sure about the how to convert image+text+background into data image uri .

I am beginner to php and Java script . I would appreciate help .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `GD` library in php and using AJAX.

You can refer it in the following link :

http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/

Comment: would you be able to tell how http://www.wovenlabelsuk.com/craft-hobby-labels/wl-02.html has been done